# Разбор рекурсии числа ряда Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Добрый вечер. Не могу понять действия рекурсивной функции при нахождении числа Фибоначчи.

```
 int f(int n)
 {
     if (n==1 || n==2) 
         return 1;
     if (n==0) 
         return 0;
    return f(n-1)+f(n-2);
 }
 int main()
 {
     cout<<f(6)<<endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

В функции f(n-1) после "прохождения" компилятором всех значений переменной n (от 6 до 3), в f(2) возвращаемым значением является единица. Вопрос: как ЭТО возвращаемое значение влияет на следующее действие, то есть действие с f(3), затем возвращаемое значение f(3) на f(4) и так далее?

Comment: в строке `if (n==1::n==2)` явно `||` вместо `::`. И да, за такой код я бы руки отрывал... Так можно писать только на небольшом числе языков, которые оптимизируют.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут все просто - только не пользуйтесь на практике: `f(50)` не дождетесь...

Формула какая? `f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)`. Это **определение** чисел. Далее, `f(1)==f(2)==1`. Все.

А для примера посчитаем

```
f(5) = f(4) + f(3)
```

`f(4)` вызывает `f(3)` и `f(2)`, `f(3)` - `f(2)` и `f(1)`:

```
f(4) = f(3) + f(2);  f(3) = f(2) + f(1);
```

`f(3)` в левой части опять вызовет `f(2)` и `f(1)`. А они уже не вызывают никого, возвращая 1. Идем назад:

```
f(3) = 1+1 = 2; f(4) = 2+1 = 3; f(5) = 3+2 = 5;
```

Вернулись к `f(5)`. Все.

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых, числа Фибоначчи вычисляются для неотрицательных чисел, поэтому параметр следует объявить по крайней мере как имеющий тип `unsigned int`.

Функцию можно написать короче. Например

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci( n - 2 ) + fibonacci( n - 1 );
}

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << fibonacci( i ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод данной программы выглядит следующим образом

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 5
6: 8
7: 13
8: 21
9: 34
```

Рекурсивный вызов функции можно представить следующим образом

```
fibonacci( 6 ) = fibonacci( 5 ) + fibonacci( 4 )  
fibonacci( 5 ) = fibonacci( 4 ) + fibonacci( 3 )  
fibonacci( 4 ) = fibonacci( 3 ) + fibonacci( 2 )  
fibonacci( 3 ) = fibonacci( 2 ) + fibonacci( 1 )
fibonacci( 2 ) = fibonacci( 1 ) + fibonacci( 0 )
fibonacci( 1 ) = 1
fibonacci( 0 ) = 0
```

Или можно представить в виде дерева, где листья будут вызовами для функции с аргументами 0 или 1, так как эти вызовы более не вызывают функцию рекурсивно

```
                                       6
                  ------------------------------------------
                 |                                          |
                 4                     +                    5
        -------------------                        -------------------
       |                   |                      |                   |
       2         +         3                      3        +          4
   ---------           ---------              ---------           ---------
  |         |         |         |            |         |          |        | 
  0    +    1         1    +    2            1   +     2          2   +    3
                              -----                  -----      -----    -----
                             |     |                |     |    |     |  |     | 
                             0  +  1                0  +  1    0  +  1  1  +  2
                                                                            ----- 
                                                                           |     |
                                                                           0  +  1
```

Если просуммировать, например, для левой ветки, начинающейся с числа 4, то получим, что `Fibonacci( 4 )` равно (будем использовать симметричный обход дерева)

```
( 0 + 1 ) +  ( 1 + ( 0 + 1 ) ) == 3
```