# Рекурсивная функция С++ Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, числа-фибоначчи

Написать функцию, которая возвращает сумму n чисел Фибоначчи. Число n
принимается в качестве аргумента, нужно без доп. переменных только рекурсией. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разбор рекурсии числа ряда Фибоначчи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583215/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8)

Comment: если есть сложности с пониманием рекурсии, посмотрите на более простой случай:  [Найти максимум одномерного массива c помощью рекурсии C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519102/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вычислить в лоб :)

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

unsigned int sumfib(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return sumfib(n-1) + fib(n);
}
```

И посчитать для `n` эдак 45-50...

**Update**
Ладно, стёб не удался :)

Держите то, что вы хотели.

```
unsigned int sfib(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return 0;
    return sfib(n-1)+sfib(n-2)+1;
}
```

Comment: Это должна быть одна функция

Comment: И немного не правильно считает но спасибо

Comment: Ну, я считал, что нулевое и первое числа Фибоначчи - 1.

Comment: К примеру когда я ввожу 5 функция мне должна вернуть 7.
Так как вот первые пять чисел Фибоначчи ( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Да проблем... См. дополнение. Но вообще-то, если не хотите, чтоб ваш вопрос был тут же закрыт, принято давать хоть какие-то собственные наработки. А так - вы выглядите просто как сачок, решивший на шару получить решение своего ДЗ, на которое ума не хватает...

Comment: кстати почему сумма считается именно так во втором примере - не так и очевидно для среднего преподавателя)

Comment: Я понял спасибо. Первый раз зашел на подобные сайты

Comment: Тогда учтите, что принятые решения здесь принято помечать птичкой :)